# Strange redraw in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I have pared down css and html to this http://jsfiddle.net/LYME9/4/

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="firstChild">First</div>
</div>
<div class="second">
    <div class="secondsChild">
        child
    </div>
</div>

.first{
    clear:both;

}
.firstChild{
    float:left;

}
.secondsChild{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:100px;

}
```

1. Open the item in IE11.
2. When you inspect the secondsChild element, you will see the margin starts right below the "first" div.
3. Change the "first" div to have position:fixed. Inspect the secondsChild element, you will see the margin starts above the "first" text.
4. Remove the position:fixed the "first" div . Inspect the secondsChild element, you will see the margin starts above the "first" text. It isn't redrawn correctly.

Shouldn't it be redrawn the same or is there some explanation I just don't see? Haven't found any reference to this bug in the internet explorer team. Anyone experienced it before?

Answer (score 0):

The "position:" property affects the document flow.  Elements start with "position:static" which puts them into the document flow.  Adding "position:fixed" takes the element out of the document flow, so surrounding or encapsulating elements are essentially blind to the "fixed" element's size, position, etc.

The actual "margin:" setting is not changing, only the positioning of the elements!  Note that .first does not fit .firstChild once we add position:fixed.  This is because .first is out of the flow!

Try adding some colored borders to your elements so you can "see" them, just for learning purposes.  I have enumerated "position:static" so you can see that it is the same as having no position declared.

```
*{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.first{
    position:static;
    border:1px solid #f0f;
    clear:both;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.firstChild{
    border:1px solid #0f0;
    float:left;
}
.second{
   border:1px solid #00f;
}
.secondsChild{
    border:1px solid #f00;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:60px;
    width:800px
}
```